# install_extras not working?

Tags: r, devtools

I'm writing an R package and trying to use the `.install_extras` feature described in [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Writing-package-vignettes).  This document says that: "To install any other files from the vignettes directory, include a file vignettes/.install_extras which specifies these as Perl-like regular expressions on one or more lines."

I have created this file and it contains the following single line.

```
myfile.png
```

The png file is present in the vignettes directory but when I install the package, using `devtools::install()`, the file doesn't get copied to doc/ folder of the installation (or inst/doc of the development directory).

I've checked various packages on Github that use this feature (e.g. [Rcppzigguart](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppziggurat/tree/master/vignettes)) and as far as I can tell, it should work.

Any ideas?  This is with R 3.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I feel a bit silly but the problem was that you have to manually `build_vignettes()` before `install()`.  That seems counter-intuitive to me: shouldn't `install` do everything necessary to install a package?

Comment: Send feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when trying to get a citations file `bibliography.bib` located in `vignettes/` copied to `inst/doc`. This is necessary when you want to use the same citations `.bib` file from other documents, such as *README.Rmd*.

The `bibliography.bib` file is not copied automatically to `inst/doc` when you do install/build/reload; you have to explicitly declare the `.bib` file in `.install_extras`. Additionally, you have to run `devtools::build_vignettes()`. Then, the `.bib` file will be available under `inst/doc` ready to be referenced by any document in the package by using something like this:

`bib_file <- system.file("doc", "bibliography.bib", package = "myPkg")`.

I use it along with the package `knitcitations` when I require to cite a source in the README or an example notebook.

f0nzie